# Laravel Create Model Class with tables that has a schema

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have a very simple question that somehow it might sound stupid but excuse me . I am working on a project where i use sql server with an existing database where table names are having a schema , forexample dob.Tablename . My question is , if i want to create eloquent model for Tablename , how will i name my class ?

Comment: By default laravel assumes the table name to be plural of model name however you can manually  `protected $table="table_name"`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create new model and add [`table`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) property:

```
protected $table = 'existing_table_name';
```

Comment: Thanks . This works , This was all out there from Laravel Documentation .

Answer (score 0):

Just be named the table name removing s corresponding to elequent model name.For example:- Elequent model name User then your database table name is users.